# Как спозиционировать блок по центру?

Tags: вёрстка, css

Бежевый блок — 100% в ширину. У левого `float: left;` у правого, соответственно, `float: right`. Как спозиционировать центральный блок, чтобы отступы до левого и правого блока были одинаковыми. Все три блока резиновые.

Cкриншот:

[image]

Получится ли решить без скриптов? Как будет выглядеть решение со скриптом?

Comment: Дополнительно: вы знакомы с флексами? Если нет, то советую посмотреть в их сторону. Подобного рода вещи будут решаться в 100 раз проще. Прикрепляю ссылку: http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2):

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left">1</div>
        <div class="right">2</div>
        <div class="wrapper-center">
            <div class="center">3<div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    background:red;
}
.right {
    float:right;
    width:20%;
    background:yellow;
}
.wrapper-center{
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    background:green;
}
.center {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:80%;
    background:blue;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: @ilyaloser тогда отмечайте решением: ставьте галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте флексом, вот пример:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
  min-height: 50px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="block">left</div>
      <div class="block">center</div>
      <div class="block">right<div>
    </div>
  </div>
```